# Python program doesn't name my file as I want

Tags: python, html, file

I made a Python program which writes html pages with some data.
The html files have a name containing letters, numbers and underscore:

```
something_something_54_to_218_something51.html
```

My program work perfectly in in the majority of cases but, sometimes the html file is not well named:

**I must have** : cat.html

**I finally have** : M (without extension)

As you can see python name my file with a letter (not always in uppercase) and without extension.
Note the veritable name don't always contains the letter in question but it can.

The content of the file is well written.

Here is my code which writes the file:

```py
def html_generator(self, data):
    logging.info("writing html...")
    with open(os.getcwd() + '/' + self.path + '/' + self.filename + ".html", "w") as file:
        file.write("<span>" + str(data) + "<span>")
        file.write(...)
    logging.info("html written")
```

I write also a txt file with the same name and it always works.

I tried to reproduce the error (with a case that I know wrong) but I can't : the program work at a time and not at another.

Last remark : my html files or stock in different folder with about 20 html maximum for a folder, and I don't see the error twice in a folder.

Can someone tell me how to prevent that error?

Comment: Just to note, you shouldn't have `file.close()` there - the context block started with `with open(...)` will close the file on exit

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I always closed my files instead of with but you're right

Comment: Add   `logging.info(os.getcwd() + '/' + self.path + '/' + self.filename + ".html")` after  `logging.info("writing html...")`

Comment: The string displayed seems good.